# Authors of Complementary Slackness

Tags: reference-request, optimization, linear-programming

Who were the first researchers to prove the Complementary Slackness condition for linear programming?

I believe that strong optimality was proved by Gale, Kuhn, and Tucker in 1951, but I couldn't find anywhere the reference for complementary slackness...